# Do we have any "checkuser" functionality here to ascertain details about a specific user?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, quality-evaluation

I have no interest myself in using such features.  I am primarily interested in whether moderators have any additional tools that could help ascertain the validity or personhood of a given user.

Case in point: user [Ayer AGG'TDd'E-A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/users/51409/).  Their username and the extremely disjointed nature of their posts both suggest a non-human identity.

Is this user a chatbot, or some other AI program?

- If so, do we have any policies or approaches to such user accounts?

Or is this user a human who is prone to incomprehensible word salads that resemble some kind of profound mental disorder?

→ No insult intended.  I am trying to honestly and objectively describe what I see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed their answers appear quite incoherent. As it is now, the community tools we have such as downvoting and closing questions seem to be enough to keep it in check. If it continues or if the problem worsens please raise the issues to us, and we will respond with the appropriate tools or escalate it if the issue is beyond us.

(Also I think that mods on the upper levels probably will not publicly discuss the details of their available tools to prevent malicious users from knowing and circumventing them.)

Comment: FWIW, looks like someone went further than just closing posts -- it appears that this user's questions, answers, and comments have been deleted outright.